# how do i prevent my script for waitnig for user input

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

i am writing a code that runs on remote computer using psexec, in some point of the code it stop and wait for user to press enter in order to continue , this only happens on remote! when i use local its fine, how do i prevent that and keep my code "rolling"?

code:

```
param(
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='database')] [string]$database,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='file')] [string]$file,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='server')] [string]$server,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='mailbox')] [string]$mailbox,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='all')] [switch]$all,
[string]$filename
```

)

```
if($mailbox) { $mailboxes = @(Get-Mailbox $mailbox) } ----->#it stop after this function#
```

Comment: Are you running psexec with `-d` parameter?

Comment: what do u mean -d parameter? i am kinda new in that area...

Comment: `psexec -d \\servername mycommand.ext`.

Comment: the way i run the psexec is to write the path of the psexec file in the cmd and after that my commands in powershell

Comment: "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrato\Desktop\PsExec.exe" \\10.0.1.25 -u Administrator -p Eaaa C:\WINDOWS\sysem32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files\Micosoft\Exchange Server\bin\exshell.psc1" -command ".

Comment: try to simply add the `-d` before `\\10.0.1.25`, and let me know...

Comment: i get this :C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exestarted on 10.0.1.25 w
ith process ID 5188."